# CSS How to animate angled lines with skew transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to incorporate a line that's being drawn that separates into 2 more spreading upwards and downwards by 45 degrees. This is [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/chriskaram/pen/KXOZjE).

CSS:

```
.connector {
   height: 40px;
   width: 200px;
   border-bottom: 2px solid red;
   border-right: 2px solid red;
   -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
   -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
   transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```css
.connector {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f00;
}

.connector:before,
.connector:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f00;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.connector:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="connector"></div>
```

Here is an animated version:

```css
.connector {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f00;
  animation: draw 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.up,
.down {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f00;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  animation: draw 1s linear;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="connector">
  <div class="up"></div>
  <div class="down"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are required to post your code here, not a third party site which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one. As it stands, your animated code may as well not be there at all. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood what you want. But, what about this?

https://codepen.io/pablodarde/pen/qPexVX

**html**

```
<div class="connector up"></div>
<div class="connector down"></div>
```

**css**

```
.connector {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.up {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}

.down {
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
```

Here, my animated version...

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="connector up"></div>
  <div class="connector down"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 0;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.animate {
  width: 220px;
}

.connector {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.up {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}

.down {
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.querySelector('.container').classList.add('animate');
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('.container').classList.add('animate');
}, 500);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 0;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.animate {
  width: 220px;
}

.connector {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.up {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}

.down {
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="connector up"></div>
  <div class="connector down"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does that animate the lines? Be sure you post the code here, not codepen.

Comment: Hi, @Rob yesterday, why not in codepen? This is a common practice here. I've added an animation. You can check it here https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/0dbqk6hq/.

Comment: You can use Codepen to compliment your answer but not to answer it. [mcve] If you use it strictly to answer, it should/will be closed. Codepen is not searchable from SO. If Codepen were to disappear, one day, your answer becomes useless. [This is not the same question but the reasons are similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698)

Comment: I understand @Rob, however, I always write my code here, never link only to codepen, or jsfiddle, so if someday codepen disappears, my code will still remain here. Btw, thanks for your tips.